# Asymptotically more $1324$-avoiding permutations than $1234$-avoiding permutations

Tags: combinatorics

I'm reading Miklos Bona's ``Combinatorics of Permutations'', and struggling with the exercise that shows that there are (asymptotically, as $n$ grows) more permutations of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ that avoid the pattern $1324$ than that avoid the pattern $1234$.

[**Edit**: a permutation $a_1a_2a_3\ldots a_n$ of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ *avoids* the pattern $1324$ if there are no four indices $i < j < k <l$ (not necessarily consecutive) such that $a_l$ is the largest element in $\{a_i,a_j,a_k,a_l\}$, $a_j$ is the second largest, $a_k$ is the third largest, and $a_i$ is the smallest; and similarly for avoiding other patterns.]

He defines an equivalence relation on permutations of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ by declaring two permutations equivalent if they have the same set of left-to-right minima, in the same positions, and the same set of right-to-left maxima, in the same positions.

Each class can be encoded by a string of length $n$ consisting of the l-to-r minima and the r-to-l maxima in their correct positions, and $\star$'s everywhere; from this it can be read off easily which of the entries are minima and which are maxima .

He then shows that each class contains exactly one $1234$-avoiding permutation and at least one $1324$-avoiding permutation, and that the class
$$
n~n-1~n-2~\ldots~9~8~3~\star~1~\star~7~\star~5
$$
($n, n-1, \ldots, 9, 8, 3, 1$ are the l-to-r minima; $7, 5$ are the r-to-l maxima) has two $1324$-avoiding permutation. This shows that there are more $1324$-avoiding permutations than $1234$-avoiding permutations.

He then argues that there are lots of classes that have at least two $1324$-avoiding permutations, namely all those whose encodings end with $3~\star~1~\star~7~\star~5$.

I'm fine with everything so far. But then he concludes with the statement ``[these] classes constitute at least a constant fraction of all ... classes''. If this is true, all is fine, but I can't seem to see how to argue this fact. I don't see it being helpful to try to enumerate classes whose encodings end with $3~\star~1~\star~7~\star~5$, since I don't know the total number of classes to compare my count with; and I can't see a way of grouping all classes on $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ into blocks of some fixed size such that each block is naturally associated with one classes whose encoding ends with $3~\star~1~\star~7~\star~5$.

Any ideas on how I should proceed?

Comment: This is highly surprising to me. I would expect there to be exactly the same number via symmetry. If you have a $(1324)$ avoiding permutation, can't you generate a $(1234)$ avoiding one by switching the $2$s and $3$s? That would destroy any existing $1234$ pattern, and would only generate a $1234$ if the original pattern was $1324$, which it wasn't by assumption. Alternatively, it seems to not be true because mathematics is invariant under change of symbology. The objects represented by $2$ and $3$ are identical in the relevant respects. Am I misunderstanding the concept?

Comment: A (1324) avoiding permutation $\sigma$, is one where there are no $i < j < k < l$ with $\sigma(i) < \sigma(k) < \sigma(j) < \sigma(l)$.   That is, some subsequence of $\sigma(1), \ldots, \sigma(n)$ has the same ordering as 1324.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_pattern for more.  So that simple switching argument doesn't hold.

Comment: Edited to clarify definition of pattern avoidance.

Comment: Just wanted to note that [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0502504.pdf) uses insertion encoding to show that $\mathrm{Av}(1324)$ grows at the rate of at least $9.35$, which is greater than $9$, the asymptotic rate of growth of $\mathrm{Av}(1234)$. Also, the classes of 1324-avoiders that contain the pattern $3\star1\star7\star5$, where $\star\star\star$ is $462$ or $624$, are _exactly_ what makes $\mathrm{Av}(1324)$ grow faster than $\mathrm{Av}(1234)$, see [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.3842.pdf).